# creating subclass object in superclass constructor goes in infinite loop java

Tags: java, oop

This might be a silly question, but please bear with me for now. I have something similar to:

```
     public class A{


    public A(){
        //Some statements here

        B bObj = new B(); //Goes in infinite loop this above statement

        (new Thread(bObj)).start();
        //Some statements here


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         A aObj = new A();

        }

    }
}

class B extends A implements Runnable{
    public testprint(){
        System.out.println("Inside testprint()");
    }
}
```

If I create a subclass object in the superclass, it goes in infinite loop, because I guess once subclass object is created it keeps calling superclass constructor which keeps creating subclass object. If I declare the subclass object in main, I get something like 'Cannot reference non-static member from static context' because my superclass object is not yet initialized. So I cannot initialize my subclass object in main.

So what would be a good way to deal with this?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a `B` object in the constructor for `A`? What's the real problem?

Comment: The implicit constructor of B is calling the one from A, that's the problem, when B is a subclass of A it needs to be `static`, that's the explanation of the second message. Also note that the code you provided doesn't even compile (`testprint` has no return type and B doesn't have a `run` method)

Comment: @Ted If I create a B object in main method, I get the  'Cannot reference non-static member from static context'  message. So I was doing it from A's constructor :P

Comment: What do you mean by "what would be a good way to deal with this?"  What do you actually want your code to do?

Comment: Please post the code that generated the error "Cannot reference non-static member . . .".

Comment: _"So I cannot initialize my subclass object in main."_ Don't put main() in your A class if you are going to extend it with B. Make A and B inner classes or put them in another source file.

Comment: @Radiodef A and B are big and B has another subclass. and there is a class C that extends A. Putting A and B will in one class will make it too big. I would like it in one .java file so that I can compile it easily from command line.

Comment: @user2441441 That's why God made build tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things I see going on that's wrong.  First, as per the comments, you can't create an instance of B in the constructor of B's parent class.  That would be an infinite loop.

Also, I see you call "new bObj".  You meant new B() I assume?

You want to create an instance of B instead of A, then in B's constructor, when starting the thread, you'd want to pass "this" to the Thread object, rather than trying to create a new instance.

And lastly, you really shouldn't try starting the thread in the constructor anyway.  You'd effectively be passing, to the Thread class, an object that's not fully constructed yet.  Should start it after the object is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that every `B` is an `A`.  So every time you try to create a `B`, you are in fact creating an `A`.

Now look at your code again.  In your constructor for `A`, which of course gets called every time you create an `A`, you've said "start by creating an `A`".  Were you not expecting an infinite loop?

Comment: I found that it does go in infinite loop. I was just wondering what would be a good way to do, what I want to do, without the infinite loop.

Comment: If what you want to do is make an A class, extend it with B and create a B in the A constructor, you can't do that without an infinite loop. It necessarily creates one. If all you want to do is make an A class, extend it with B and create one of each, don't mix B in with A. Make an outer class with main() and put A and B somewhere else.

Comment: @DavidWallace What the OP should not do is create a class C that extends B and create an instance of C in the B constructor.

Comment: @David I don't see how my statement could be constructed in that way. It clearly added a qualifier asking what would be a 'good way' to do what I want to do. If my question doesn't demonstrate what I want to do, then you should ask me to clarify it further, and I'd would happily oblige. I think your above comment is uncalled for.

Comment: Fine, if you don't want me to try to help you, I'll spend my time somewhere else.  You're welcome, by the way, for my help so far.